# Non-trivial intersection of all non- trivial normal subgroups of a finite group

Tags: group-theory

Is it possible to give a full description of all finite groups that have a non-trivial intersection of all their non-trivial normal subgroups?

Thanks,  Michiel

Comment: Such groups are described [here](https://groupprops.subwiki.org/wiki/Monolithic_group)

Comment: This is equivalent to having a unique minimal normal subgroup.  Such a group is often called monolithic, and the minimal normal subgroup is the monolith. If the monolith is non-abelian, then the group has a pretty restricted structure. Otherwise, not that much can be said.

Comment: They are the groups with a unique minimal normal subgroups. In the case of $p$-groups, they are the ones with cyclic centres. The difficulty with this kind of question is what exactly do you mean by a "full description". What sort of answer are you looking for?

Comment: @Crostul That is hardly a description! It is little more than a definition.

Comment: @ Derek: with full description I mean "a as complete list as possible ". Examples of such groups are the simple groups, $Q_8$, $S_3$,...

Comment: It is not possible to simply  list all of the groups with this property, even in the case of $p$-groups with cyclic centres.

Comment: Thanks Derek. 'Characterizing' these groups is maybe a better wording than 'describing' or 'listing' them

Answer (score 1):

Here is a description of the finite groups $G$ with a minimal normal nonabelian subgroup $N$.

In this case, $N \cong S^n$ for some $n \ge 1$, where $S$ is nonabelian and simple. We can embed $S$ in its automorphism group $A$ by identifying it with the subgroup of inner automorphisms of $S$.

Then $G$ is a subgroup of the wreath product $W = A \wr S_n$, such that $N$ is the subgroup $S^n$ of the base group of $W$, and $G$ projects onto a transitive subgroup of $S_n$.

Any group $G$ satisfying those conditions has $N$ as a unique minimal normal subgroup.